# MathOperator in beamer with LuaLaTeX and cyrillic text

Tags: beamer, fonts

I define Sans Serif fonts for text for my beamer presentation in Russian:

```
\usepackage{luatextra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic, Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{CMU Typewriter Text}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmainfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
```

I would like to use Sans Serif fonts everywhere except equations.  To do it, I write

```
\mode<presentation> {
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} ... }
```

But there is the problem with option `DeclareMathOperator`. For instance, I write

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{\mathrm{Tr}\,}
```

and obtain Sain Serif typesetting of this operator instead of desired Serif format. How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Please, make the code snippets into a full (minimal) document showing the issue.

Comment: Well, with the edit you left even less clues than before.

Comment: @egreg , it is the minimal example. I defien Sans Serif fonts for text in preambule. Than, I try to use \mathrm and it obviously uses Sans Serif font. I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Without a *complete* example showing the issue, nobody can guess. By an example I mean (minimal) code that goes from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and shows the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Basic, Ligatures=TeX}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfonttt{CMU Typewriter Text}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmainfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{\symrm{Tr}\,}
\begin{document}

\frame{Tr $ \Tr $ }

\end{document}
```

[image]